# Waiting for multiple Events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm currently developing an app mainly for self-education purposes and since I'm still not completely used to js I could use some help for my problem:

In my app I'm using a Javascript library (jqMobi) which is used for DOM manipulation, page transitions, ajax calls etc and I'm also using phonegap to access device features such as the geolocation.

When I start up my app I want to get the geolocation of the device, send an ajax (jsonp) request to my server (including the geolocation of the device) which returns an array of JSON objects which I will use to build up a list.

Before I can get the geolocation I need to wait for phonegap to load. And before using jqMobi to make the ajax call and handle the response I need to wait for it to load as well.

So I basically have to events im listening to

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",execute_this,false);  //jqMobi is now ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", execure_sth, false); //Phonegap is now ready
```

How do I execute a function as soon as both of these events have fired and not before?

If I'd use jQuery I'd make use of its `$.Deferred` objects and its When ... Then Function but since I don't have access to these I'm looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",execute_this,false);
function execute_this(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", execure_sth, false);
}
function execute_sth(){
//your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. One question though: What happens if for example the deviceready event occurs before DOMContentLoaded? Would it still call execute_sth?

Comment: See according to the phonegap site http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html
"Typically, you will want to attach an event listener with document.addEventListener once the HTML document's DOM has loaded."

Answer (score 27):

You can make Promises that resolve when the events fire, and wait for both of them to be ready.

```
var dcl = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",resolve,false);
})
var deviceready = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", resolve, false);
})

Promise.all([dcl, deviceready]).then(function() {
    //both are ready
});
```

Answer (score 26):

At first blush, something like this would definitely work:

```
var executed_this = false, executed_sth = false;

function execute_this() {
  executed_this = true;
  combined_execution();
}

function execute_sth() {
  executed_sth = true;
  combined_execution();
}

function combined_execution() {
  if (executed_this && executed_sth) {
    // magic!
  }
}
```

But is not extensible (what if you want a third event to wait on?). A counter would work:

```
var wait_on = 2;

function execute_this() {
  combined_execution();
}

function execute_sth() {
  combined_execution();
}

function combined_execution() {
  wait_on--;
  if (wait_on === 0) {
    // magic!
  }
}
```

Is more extensible, but that assumes that the events only fire once. Either way, these are the primatives that can control the type of flow control you are asking for, and everything else is (for the most part) a higher level abstraction on these two.

Comment: ONE LINER!! wooo! `if (--waitOn !== 0) return false` :)

Comment: This worked for me in my scenario I have 2 ajax calls that are done in parallel and I want to only run a function once both are done. And I don't want to slow them down by running them in series

Answer (score 0):

Merged a few of the answers here into `waitForEvents(eventTarget, eventNames);`

Usage:

```js
waitForEvents(window, 'DOMContentLoaded,deviceready').then(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Source:

```js
/**
 * Wait for multiple DOM events to fire
 * @param {object} eventTarget - element to listen for events on (default document)
 * @param {Array<string>|string} eventNames - array or csv string of event names
 * @returns {Promise<Array>} resolves with array of event objects
 */
function waitForEvents(eventTarget, eventNames) {

    eventTarget = eventTarget || document;
    eventNames = (!Array.isArray(eventNames)) ? String(eventNames).split(',') : eventNames;

    // clean event names
    eventNames = eventNames.map(function(item) {
        return String(item).trim();
    })
    .filter(function(item) {
        return item !== '';
    });

    var items = [];

    // create a promise to wait for each event
    var listeners = eventNames.map(function(eventName) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            eventTarget.addEventListener(eventName, function(e) {
                items.push(e);
                resolve();
            }, false);
        });
    });

    // resolve once all events have fired
    return Promise.all(listeners).then(function() {
        return Promise.resolve(items);
    });
}
```

Gist on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/john-doherty/ddbf13e625c52c7b8bb9645a39a3fb8b)

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` is the way to go, but for fun (and laziness at importing a polyfill), I came up with this little solution:

```js
executedCount = 0

function onExecuted() {
    document.body.dispatchEvent(new Event('executedCountIs'+(++executedCount)));
}

function execute_this() {
    onExecuted()
}

function execute_sth() {
    onExecuted()
}

function main() {
    document.body.addEventListener('executedCountIs2', doStuffWhenBothAreReady)
    execute_this()
    execute_sth()
}
```

I'm assuming the Javascript engine protects me from a race condition here.